# Spring: Load additional properties depending on profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to load an additional .properties file with Spring if and only if an additional profile is active. E.g. if profile "foo" is active, I want to load foo.properties. This pseudo code is what I want, assuming "spring.profiles.active=default,foo":

```
<context:property-placeholder 
location="classpath:component.properties${(spring.profiles.active).contains('foo') ? ',classpath:foo.properties' : ''}" />
```

Is there a way to do this in Spring?

Comment: I suggest adding Spring Boot to your application, which supports this out-of-the-box.

Comment: I agree with @M.Deinum , but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191736/spring-xml-dynamic-property-placeholder-construction/28194233#28194233) which uses SpEL to do something similar indirectly via `properties-ref`. Just put your `util:properties` in the profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this if you are not dealing with multiple profile at same time.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />
```